# Log4j generate different files with the same content

Tags: file, logging, configuration, log4j, appender

I'm working with a Java application that integrates log4j. For a new development I would need that instead of generating a file I will generate two, one per country that is accessed from the application web. Both would have the same log records that are found throughout my application.

I configured the configuration using an .xml file:

```html
<!-- Appenders -->
     <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern"
        value="jeveris: %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c - %m%n" />
      </layout>
     </appender>

     
     <appender name="One-Console" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Console.log" />
      <param name="Append" value="true" />
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="2MB" />
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern"
        value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c - %m%n" />
      </layout>
     </appender>


     
     <category name="com.example.one.web">
      <level value="debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="One-Console" />
     </category>
     
     
     <root>
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
      <level value="debug" />
     </root>
    </log4j:configuration>
```

Could someone guide me, tell me if it is possible or help me find the solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2+ log files that will print the same content, then you could fine 2 different files in your  tag like so:

```
<configuration status="OFF">
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">/your/file/path/</Property>
    <Property name="log-country-name1">Country1</Property>
    <Property name="log-country-name2">Country2</Property>
    <!-- more if necessary -->
    <Property name="log-pattern">%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t|%c{1}] %m\n</Property>
    <Property name="rollover-strategy-max">5</Property>
    <Property name="rolling-size-based">10 MB</Property>
</Properties>
<appenders>

    <!--uncomment following if want to print to console as well -->
    <!-- <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>${log-pattern}</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console> -->

 <RollingFile name="INFO" fileName="${log-path}/${log-country-name1}-logger.log" filePattern="${log-path}/${log-project-name}-debug-%d-%i.log.zip">
    <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>${log-pattern}</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${rolling-size-based}" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${rollover-strategy-max}" />
</RollingFile>

 <RollingFile name="INFO" fileName="${log-path}/UpdaterLocal-logger.log" filePattern="${log-path}/${log-country-name2}-debug-%d-%i.log.zip">
    <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>${log-pattern}</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${rolling-size-based}" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${rollover-strategy-max}" />
</RollingFile>

</appenders>
<Loggers>
    <logger name="io.switchfour" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="INFO" level="info" />
    </logger>
</Loggers>
```

The above will create /your/file/path/Country1-logger.log and /your/file/path/Country2-logger.log and will write all entries that are INFO or higher to both files.  Your log file should be identical.

Comment: First thanks for replying.

I think you explain me wrong. What I wanted to say is that I need you to write to me in a file or another depending on the country even though the messages and the package are the same. That is to say we imagine a message of log "Starting application" if the user selects spain it will be written in the file country1.log if it selects England it would write in country2.log

Comment: Are you wanting to do something like this (see Property Substitution section)? http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for the information. That's what I needed